# android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources Null pointer exception

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, decode

I am having  a `nullPointerException` when I want to start `decoding` a `bitmap`.

This is the code I am getting an error on:

```
public void decodeBitmap(int bitmapID){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    **BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), bitmapID, options);**
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;

    Log.v("decodeBitmap","imageHeight: "+imageHeight+". imageWidth:
   "+imageWidth+". imageType: "+imageType);
}
```

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), bitmapID, options);` is the line of code i am getting an error on.

I call this method `onButtonClick` in my activity.

This is a method call:

```
decodeBitmap(R.drawable.rising_sun_blue);
```

Can anybody point me to the problem here?

Comment: in decode bitmap try getResources.getdrawable in your function call

Comment: Likely you instantiated the activity class yourself with `new` which is something you never should be doing. Please post full stacktrace and some code around where you're calling the method.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. This is called from the main activity.
And there is not that much code around this. The app starts, I declare all the variables and set onClickListeners. And when I click on a button, I call this method decodeBitmap(R.drawable.rising_sun_blue);

Comment: @ Illegal Argument I don't see why would I do that when BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources, int, options) doesn't accept drawable

Comment: If you look at the [`ContextWrapper getResources()` code](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#87) you can see that the only way for NPE there is if the base context `mBase` is null. The easiest way for null base context is instantiating the activity yourself. But please post the full stacktrace and some relevant code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was the problem.

I put the whole decodeBitmap(int bitmapID) in a static Controller class, and I was calling that function from the Activity.
And ofc, I cannot reach resources that way, hence the null pointer exception.

Therefore, I will leave this answer here, if someone in the future does the same thing.